# How to change charset of Jupyter notebooks on Bluemix

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I began to use Apache Spark service on Bluemix and collect/analyze Twitter data.

I have to use Japanese characters and display on Jupyter notebook to create demo stream, but default charset is not UTF-8 but US-ASCII (I issued "scala.io.Codec.default.charSet" and checked), so my Japanese output is corrupted like "???".

Does anyone know how to change default charset of notebook from US-ASCII to UTF-8?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only US-ASCII characters are supported. We have raised a request to make the changes to support UTF-8. There is no code workaround as this needs to be implemented at JVM level.